# Is there a command to go to the previous thread in gdb without remembering the thread number?

Tags: gdb

`gdb` switches a thread when the appropriate breakpoint fires.
I need to remember the thread number to come back with `thread n`.
Is there a special command to return to the thread where step-by-step execution was performed?

```
(gdb) n
57          m_app = create_app();
(gdb) n
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffdfffd700 (LWP 32059)]

Thread 9 "foo" hit Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000421ef0 in App::App()@plt ()
(gdb) # command to return to the interrupted thread
```

Comment: Have you tried [`set scheduler-locking step`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html#index-scheduler-locking-mode)? In this mode the other threads would stay stopped while you step.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup custom GDB prompt to show current thread number with [`set extended-prompt`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Prompt.html):

```
(gdb) set extended-prompt <\t>
```

Every time you use any of GDB commands current thread number will be printed in GDB prompt, for example:

```
<1> thread 
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7dcd740 (LWP 148411))]
<1> info threads 
  Id   Target Id                                  Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7dcd740 (LWP 148411) "a.out" main () at /home/ks/t.c:7
<1>
```

With that information in GDB prompt you can return to interrupted thread with:

```
thread <id_taken_from_prompt_before_interrupt>
```